# How do I get my command to ignore other users but allow the original user to respond?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a `work` command that requires a correct answer to give money. It works just fine when no one messages in between the original "question" and the answer, but if any message interrupts that, it completely cancels out the rest of it. I'm almost certain it's an issue with my filter, but I have no clue how to fix it. I've watched a couple YouTube videos on it, as well as reading a few other help forum posts and it still won't work the proper way.

Logs gives the following error `Cannot read property 'content' of undefined` which occurs when 'user 2' says anything after 'user 1' uses the original `work` command but before 'user 1' can use the correct answer, in this case "fire"

I've tried moving around the `filter` to every which way I could even think of; I also tried getting rid of `Authorid` and just using `message.author.id`. I also swapped out member for author in the same `filter` part which left the code working, but still not working the way I want it to.

I guess my main big question after all that is how the heck do I get it to ignore any other user's input but still allow the original command user to continue?

I edited in the part that was suggested but the command still ends in an error message. It filters for the sender for sure since it runs fine when the original author responds, but if someone else responds, it reverts to the error.

```
else {
    message.channel.send(question).then(r => {
      const filter = msg => msg.author.id === message.author.id;
      };
      message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 }).then(collected => {
        const response = collected.first();
        let answer = response.content;
        if (result === 0 && answer.toLowerCase() === "fire") {
          let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${message.author.username} went to work!`)
            .setColor("#ffd1dc")
            .setDescription(`You received ${amount} Quoins!`)
            .setFooter(
              message.member.user.username,
              message.member.user.displayAvatarURL
            );
          message.channel.send(embed);
          db.add(`qnhCurrency_${message.author.id}`, amount);
          db.set(`work_${message.author.id}`, Date.now());
          return;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `filter` needs to check if the reply was made by the command `author`, use this as your `filter`: `const filter = msg => msg.author.id === message.author.id`

Comment: I just tried that and it's still sending the same error message in logs when there's an 'interruption'